# macos pkg: How to log bash errors

Tags: bash, macos, pkgbuild

I have a macos app with a pkg installer. The pkg has a postinstall.sh and a preinstall.sh.

On most machines it works fine but for certain customers I get reports that the script has failed.

I've asked the users to send me the installer logs but those don't contain the actual bash error only something like this:

Sep 14 15:04:16 Filestars-Mac-Mini installd[2540]: PackageKit: Install Failed: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “Filestar.21.0.12.0.osx-x64.pkg”." UserInfo={NSFilePath=./preinstall, NSURL=file:///Users/filestar/repos/Filestar/Filestar.Installer/macOs/Output/Filestar.21.0.12.0.osx-x64.pkg#Filestar.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=com.Filestar.pkg.Filestar, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while running scripts from the package “Filestar.21.0.12.0.osx-x64.pkg”.} {
NSFilePath = "./preinstall";
NSLocalizedDescription = "An error occurred while running scripts from the package \U201cFilestar.21.0.12.0.osx-x64.pkg\U201d.";
NSURL = "file:///Users/filestar/repos/Filestar/Filestar.Installer/macOs/Output/Filestar.21.0.12.0.osx-x64.pkg#Filestar.pkg";
PKInstallPackageIdentifier = "com.Filestar.pkg.Filestar";
}

How can I get the actual error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During your `preinstall.sh` and `postinstall.sh` scripts, append to a log file. For example, you can `rm -rf /var/tmp/Filestar.log` during `preinstall.sh` then append anything you deem interesting there. Doing the same for `postinstall.sh`. Then if the user reports an issue have them send you the log file.